# Find a good colour match from an RGB to a CMYK / spot colour that will print well

Tags: color, cmyk, rgb, spot-color

I have a hex colour #0d152c, which is a corporate colour, when this is converted / printed in CMYK the colour doesn't convert well when printed and looks a bit washed-out because obviously CMYK has a lower colour range.

Is there a way of taking a hex colour and finding a CMYK colour that is reasonably close that will look good when printed (I think this would be called a spot colour?). When I change the colour mode in Adobe illustrator the colour on screen doesn't change, and is still rendered on screen as an RGB colour because that's what my monitor uses.

I am new to Graphic Design so please be kind :)

Comment: Hi The Chewy, have you checked if [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110787/120647), or [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92131/120647), or [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/70196/120647), or [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/79815/120647) (there are many more) answer your question? Try typing "rgb cmyk hex" at the search text field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mismatched CMYK Values](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34993/mismatched-cmyk-values)

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide a little bit more information regarding the printing of this color: 1. Where (which continent on the globe) you will print? 2. On what material you want to print (coated paper, uncoated paper, plastics, etc.)? 3. What kind if technology will be most often be used for printing (offset, digital inkjet, digital toner, office printers, heatset, etc.)?

Answer (score -6):

hex color is a special ink--you cannot match it in cmyk--you need to purchase the hex ink

Comment: Hex color is an ink???????????

Comment: [**Hexachrome**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexachrome) was a printing process using orange and green + CMYK. It has been discontinued. Although, I HIGHLY doubt the question is asking about Hexachrome.

Comment: What the hex, is a hex ink?